# Is it wise to stream file over vertx event bus

Tags: java, microservices, vert.x

We have set of services in a vertx cluster. We serve web front end through a API gateway which is one service within the cluster. Client ask a requirement for download some data as a CSV file. It should be transmitted as bellow.

Service A --(Event bus)---> API gateway ---(Web socket)---> Browser

My question is, is it wise to stream such file over event bus from Service A to API gateway? (File may get as large as 100 MB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but its not designed for it. Will create congestion because the entirety of the file will be kept in memory until transfer is complete.  Just set up a http server, communicate the url through a consumer and upload it over http. Then you get all http support as well.

If you don't want a perm http server for it, just start one whenever a request for an upload comes in.